# Azure DevOps Artifacts - Retention policy - static date

Tags: azure-devops, package

I need to provide packages for a period of 4 year
Is there a way to set a static retention, keep all packages newer then X years

Maximum number of versions per package: 5000(max), if I set it at max it can help but is not 100% correct, and we will have some garbage in the future
Days to keep recently downloaded packages: 365(max) this is the reason we temporary lost one package, it was not set to 365, this can help but is not sure

I disabled the retention for now, but I will like to have a retention policy in the future

Retention base on regex will be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how Artifact Retention policy works: When the package versions exceed `Maximum number of versions per package`, the policy will check the exceeded versions, if there are versions downloaded during `Days to keep recently downloaded packages`, the policy won't delete them, otherwise the exceeded versions will be deleted.

For example:

I have two feeds with 16 versions of a package, both settings as below:

[image]

If I never download any versions, the exceeded oldest ones will be deleted:

[image]

If I download the oldest two, then the oldest two won't be deleted temporarily, they will be deleted after `Days to keep recently downloaded packages`:

[image]

Regarding your idea, you could submit a feature request in the following link:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion

Comment: Hi,
Thank you. I used the current setting, I increased the download retention to 365  but we are not 100% safe. 
I also open a suggestion, didn't had a reply yet. 

We will have some garbage now :D because the develop packages will be there for 1 year